# How do I disable the double mouse cursor in Teamviewer?

Tags: display, teamviewer, duplicate, mouse-cursor, lid

I'm seeing a double mouse cursor when using TeamViewer. It happens whenever I move the mouse. It's like there's a mouse trail or a slow mouse. Why is it that? How do I get rid of it?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to modify the registriy, just untick the box marked show remote cursor in Teamviewer

Answer (score 0):

The double mouse cursor issue occurs on some systems when the notebook lid is closed or the remote monitor is disabled or unplugged. It is caused by Teamviewer displaying both the current cursor and a remote cursor. It's not really a cursor trail.

To remove the double cursor, you'll need to modify a key in the registry. Create a .REG file (e.g. TeamviewerDisableDoubleCursor.reg) with the following contents. To use, open a CMD windows and enter "regedit TeamviewerDisableDoubleCursor.reg". Restart Teamviewer or system. Teamviewer says they'll implement an option to disable the remote mouse in a future update.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\TeamViewer]
"DisableDuplicationAPI"=dword:00000001
```